# Compute integral using Cauchy Principal Value

Tags: contour-integration, cauchy-principal-value

Using the Cauchy Principal Value, I need to compute the following integral 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(ax) - \cos(bx)}{x^2}dx$$

I have used the standard semi-circle contour with an indentation around the singularity at $x=0$. However integrating around the outer semicircle and smaller one around $0$, I find they have no contribution to the integral and the residue is also $0$. However I know the integral is not equal to $0$.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: The residue is $0$, however you miscalculated in assuming that the integral along the semicircle vanishes. $\cos$ grows exponentially in both the lower and upper half planes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the contour of a semi-circle that avoids the singularity at $(0,0)$ of radius $\varepsilon$.  Notice the line integral of the arc of radius $\lim_{R \to \infty} R$ equals 0 from Jordan's lemma.  Also, consider $\cos{x}=\Re{\left(e^{ix}\right)}$, so we will take the real part of the integral.  By Cauchy's 1st theorem you're left with:
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos{ax}-\cos{bx}}{x^2} \; dx =-\int_{\pi}^0 \frac{e^{ia \varepsilon e^{i \theta}}-e^{ib \varepsilon e^{i \theta}}}{{\left(\varepsilon e^{i \theta}\right)}^2} \; i\varepsilon e^{i \theta} d\theta$$
Use the maclaurin series of $e^x$:
$$I=i\int_0^{\pi} \frac{ia \varepsilon e^{i \theta}-ib \varepsilon e^{i \theta}}{\varepsilon e^{i \theta}} \; d\theta$$
$$I=-\int_0^{\pi} {a -b } \; d\theta$$
$$I=\Re{\left(\pi \left(b-a\right)\right)}=\boxed{\pi \left(b-a\right)}$$

Comment: How does the integral on the arc $|z| = R$ go to $0$ ? Cosine grows exponentially on the arc but the denominator is polynomial. I'm not saying it necessarily doesn't, but an explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I am not too confident with my answer, but according to https://books.google.com/books?id=61BO2UY9QN4C&pg=PA216&lpg=PA216&dq=cos(x)/x%5E2+with+jordans+lemma&source=bl&ots=5epRkAIbYl&sig=ACfU3U1-cK_3kpuQCYX61PdK4u_xXdd0uQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQ0bG8uO7pAhWFneAKHXdtB00Q6AEwDXoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false (page 216), the integral along arc of radius R equals zero because the degree of the denominator is > degree of numerator + 1

Comment: I see. There is an extra step missing where you say the integral is the real part of $\frac{e^{iaz} - e^{ibz}}{z^2}$. Then on the upper half plane since the imaginary part is positive the exponentials are decaying i.e. $ia(iy) = -ay < 0$

Comment: Yes, thanks I will fix it.  Sorry if I was a bit hostile.

Comment: No not hostile at all! I promise you were delightful to speak to.

Answer (score 4):

The integral can be rewritten as a double integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(ax)-\cos(bx)}{x^2}\:dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_a^b \frac{\sin(yx)}{x}\:dy\:dx$$

Swapping the order of integration gives us

$$\int_a^b \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin z}{z} \:dz \:dy = \int_a^b \pi \:dy = \pi(b-a)$$

by using the substitution $z = yx$ on the inside. The sinc integral can be done by considering a rectangular contour instead of a semicircle. This insight means you could use a rectangular contour for the original integral if you wish.

Comment: I believe OP is looking for the solution with contour integration

Comment: @Ty the sinc integral can be derived via contour integration, which is done many times on this site already.